# Content doesn't update on route change

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, url-routing

When I change route, from say `/set/1` to `/set/2`, then it still shows the information from `/set/1` until I manually refresh the page, I've tried adding `$route.refresh` to the `ng-click` of the links to these pages, but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Below is the routing code, this works fine, all routing is done via links, just `<a>` tags that href to the route.

```
angular.module('magicApp', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'
    }).when('/set', {
        redirectTo: '/sets'
    }).when('/set/:setID', {
        controller: 'SetInformationController',
        templateUrl: 'pages/set.html'
    }).when('/card', {
        redirectTo: '/cards'
    }).when('/card/:cardID', {
        controller: 'CardInformationController',
        templateUrl: 'pages/card.html'
    }).when('/sets', {
        controller: 'SetListController',
        templateUrl: 'pages/sets.html'
    }).when('/cards', {
        controller: 'CardListController',
        templateUrl: 'pages/cards.html'
    }).when('/search/:searchterm', {
        controller: 'SearchController',
        templateUrl: 'pages/search.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

Below is the code for the SetListController, it uses the routeParams to grab the correct information from a service, which works, when I go to `/set/1` then it returns the right information, if I then go back then go to `/set/2` it still shows the information from set 1, until I refresh the page.

```
.controller('SetInformationController', function($scope, $routeParams, $route, SetInformationService, CardSetInformationService) {
$scope.set = [];
$scope.cards = [];

function init() {
    SetInformationService.async($routeParams.setID).then(function(d) {
        $scope.set = d;
    });
    CardSetInformationService.async($routeParams.setID).then(function(d) {
        $scope.cards = d;
    })
}

init();
})
```

The HTML itself has no reference to the controller, or anything like that, just the objects in the scope, namely `set` and `cards`.

Comment: Please paste code showing your route config, and the code used to change the route.

Comment: I've edited the main post with it.

Comment: you do not have a controller for route `/set/:setID`

Comment: `/set/1` and `/set/2` are the same route by your config, so they will both show pages/set.html.

Comment: @DavidWood: It would be best to prepare a fiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: They should show the same page, but if I go from `/set/1` to `/set/2` the content remains the same as it was.

Comment: Can you show the controller and html code please. I assume you process the `setID` in the controller and use it to update the display in `set.html`?

Comment: I've added more to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The problem wasn't actually with the routing it was with my service, here was the service before:

```
.factory('SetInformationService', function($http) {
  var promise;
  var SetInformationService = {
    async: function(id) {
      if ( !promise ) {
          // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
          promise = $http.get('http://api.mtgdb.info/sets/' + id).then(function (response) {
           // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
           console.log("Set Information");
           console.log(response);
           // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
           return response.data;
           });
      }
      // Return the promise to the controller
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return SetInformationService;
})
```

where it should have been:

```
.factory('SetInformationService', function($http) {
  var promise;
  var SetInformationService = {
    async: function(id) {
      // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
      promise = $http.get('http://api.mtgdb.info/sets/' + id).then(function (response) {
        // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
        console.log("Set Information");
        console.log(response);
        // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
        return response.data;
      });
      // Return the promise to the controller
      return promise;
    }
  };
  return SetInformationService;
})
```